# Scala IntelliJ warning "dynamic invocation could be replaced with a constructor invocation"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

Why does Intellij give this warning, what does it mean, how can I make it better ?

```
import akka.actor.Props

object Router {
  def props(config: Config, addresses: Set[Address]): Props =
    Props(classOf[Router], config, addresses)
    // "dynamic invocation could be replaced with a constructor invocation"
```

If I the Props inplace I get a different warning.

```
system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Router], config, addresses))
// could be replaced with factory method call
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you missing a `class Router` definition with a constructor that takes a `Config` instance and a collection of `Address` instances? Something like...

```
class Router(config: Config, addresses: Set[Address]) extends Actor
```

If so, then try the following slight modification to your companion object.

```
object Router {

  def props(config: Config, addresses: Set[Address]): Props = {
    Props(new Router(config, addresses))
  }

}
```

This follows [best practices](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/actors.html#recommended-practices) for creating actors and will probably get rid of the warning.